# SQL Server : optimize constraint for perform a query bases on 2 columns

Tags: sql-server

I am creating a table `Brands` with the following schema :

```
UserId
CarId
Brand
```

- The `UserId` references the `id` of an user in the `user` table
- The `CarId` references the `id` of a car in the `car` table

The only query that I will use is a search bases on these 2 columns, to get the corresponding brand.

So my question was about the constraint part, as I am a beginner, I would like to know which type of constraint to use (index, primary key, clustered or non clustered, on each field or on the 2 fields together) to have my query the more optimized possible.

This is my script right now :

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[Brands]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [Brands]
    (
        UserId BIGINT NOT NULL
            CONSTRAINT [FK_Brands_Users] 
            FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Users] (UserId),
        CarId BIGINT NOT NULL
            CONSTRAINT [FK_Brands_Cars] 
            FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Cars] (CarId),
        Brand nvarchar(15),             
    );
END
GO

ALTER TABLE [Brands]
ADD CONSTRAINT [Unique_UserId_BrandId] UNIQUE(UserId, BrandId);
GO
```

Comment: constraint does not affect query performance. It is the index that helps

Comment: So I should create a primary key on each field, or a primary key including both fields?

Comment: you can only have one primary key in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a primary key including both fields. When you define a primary key it automatically create a clustered index. Also your primary key has a unique constraint build in. Your table is now a heap the way you wrote it here above which is not good. You can additionally create an extra non-clustered index on CarId. Having an additional non-clustered index on UserId is not usefull I think. The column UserId can use the clustered index because it's the first field in the clustered index but I'm not sure about that.